# make clearml agent do not install envs for every task

Tags: clearml

I want make my clearml agent do not install python envs for every task, it take too long.

I tried setup config like: package_manager.system_size_packages=true, but it doesn't work.

clearml agent won't install python envs anymore

Answer (score 1):

To make the agent skip creating a new venv, you can pass the following environment variable, pointing to the python binary the agent should run: `CLEARML_AGENT_SKIP_PIP_VENV_INSTALL=/path/to/python/binary`